# Why this Regular Expression doesn't work?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression to extract two tokens, delimiters [**'**] and words between apostrophes like '**Stack Overflow**'. The question is, why this regular expression doesn't work?

Regex:

```
(['])|'([^']*)'
```

Here is a link to explain it:
[Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/aO2dI2/2)

Only works extracting apostrophes but, words between apostrophes no.

NOTE: I need to extract apostrophe and any word between apostrophe by separately like 'Stack Overflow'.

The result would be like:

1. '
2. Stack Overflow
3. '

Greetings.

Comment: @JesúsA.MezaG. what if that link goes away, how would future readers know what this question is about?  Better to include the relevant parts of the question directly in the question

Comment: Ok, edited and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex says to match either a single quote or the content between quotes, but it's an exclusive or the way you have it.  To get each of them as a capture group you could use the regex:

```
(')([^']*)(')
```

to get the first quote, then everything that's not a quote then the last quote

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** Because it's [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In the `or` condition, once the first regex is matched the second regex is unnecessary to evaluated. because `True | anything` always gets `True`, right?

Consider your regex

```
regex = (['])|'([^']*)'
text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

Run regex to match string in `text`

`(['])` matches to `'` and `'`, then capture them into `$1` and `$2`.

done! (skip the second regex because you connect them with `or`)

**Another proof:**

```
regex = (['])|'([^']*)'
text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

get

```
$1 = `'`
$2 = `'`
```

but

```
regex = '([^']*)'|(['])
text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

get

```
$1 = `Stack Overflow`
```

You will see that only the first one is work!

Thus, I suggest you to use this regex instead of:

```
(')(.*?)(')
```

where you get your captured texts in `$1`, `$2`, `$3` respectively.

Note that `*?` is a non-greedy quantifier, the simple explanation is: it will not arbitrarily consume your `'`.